# no object named "pod" is registered

Tags: kubernetes

What does this mean?

```
-bash-4.2# kubectl create -f ./pod.yaml
Error: unable to recognize "./pod.yaml": no object named "pod" is registered
```

pod.yaml, capitalizing or not capitalizing 'pod' makes no difference. Validates as proper YAML.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
      hostPort: 8080
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please run `kubectl version` and report the results? I expect that either your apisver or kubectl version is outdated, and thus doesn't know about the v1 API.

For what it's worth, that pod spec works for me with both kubectl and my apiserver at version 1.0.3.

Comment: -bash-4.2# kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"0", Minor:"15+", GitVersion:"v0.15.0-123-g0ea87e48640729", GitCommit:"0ea87e486407298dc1e3126c47f4076b9022fb09", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"0", Minor:"15+", GitVersion:"v0.15.0-123-g0ea87e48640729", GitCommit:"0ea87e486407298dc1e3126c47f4076b9022fb09", GitTreeState:"clean"}

I'm using projectatomic as I had a miserable time trying to get straight binaries to run properly. Kind of depressing if that turns out to be the case, this example is word for word from their getting started docs.

Comment: Yeah, version 0.15 doesn't have the v1 API in it. Try using the docs and examples in the Kubernetes release-0.15 branch,  which use the v1beta3 API. For what it's worth, v1beta3 is very similar to v1 -- that yaml file should work if you replace the string "v1" with "v1beta3". https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/release-0.15

Comment: I'm going to see if I can figure out why atomic is giving me a ridiculously out of date version of kubernetes. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

i was able to create the pod

```
master $ kubectl create -f pod.yaml
pod/nginx created

master $ kubectl get po
NAME      READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
nginx     1/1       Running   0          1m

cat pod.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
      hostPort: 8080
```

most likely issue is with the kubernetes on your server. can you check  k8s components health status. i dont see any issue with the pod manifest. it should work